# How does Laravel keeping track of batch value?

Tags: laravel

I created some migration files which created the table "users" and "user_info".
Running `php artisan migrate` created the tables and added them to the migrations table in the database.

Then I needed to create a new column and add some new rows to the user_info table. So I created a new migration file with the same name as the first migration file which was used to create the "user_info" table.
Since Laravel adds a timestamp to the file I didn't think that would create any problems. However, in the the new migration file I used the same class name as for the the first migration file, did the changes I wanted and finally ran `php artisan migrate` again.

That seemed to create problems since I got an error saying that the class name was already in use.
So I changed the migration filename to be user_info2 and used the class name UserInfo2 and tried again.
This time it worked and the batch has been bumped up to 2 in the migration table in the database.

But how does Laravel know that the migration file actually is related to the first user_info migration file since I changed both the filename and class name? I thought they had to have the same name in order to make Laravel have control of the "batch-value".

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The batch number of the migrations is used to specify multiple migrations that were created while running `php artisan migrate`.

So for example you create two migrations: `users` and `user_info` you run `php artisan migrate` this two migrations will be created and will be referenced by the same batch number: 1.

Then you create another migration, when you migrate this migration will have the number 2 as batch number.

When you do `php artisan migrate:rollback` based on the batch number Laravel knows which migrations to rollback, in this case only one migration with the batch number of 2.

So batch in this terms means an array of migrations that has not been run. Those will be referenced by the same ID, in order to make the rollback possible.

Hope this explains a bit more.